# How to get system information on the Desktop?

Tags: desktop-customization, system-info

I am really interested to have something exactly like this on my Desktop :

[image: picture of system information on desktop]

Comment: What OS do you use? Different solution exist for different systems.

Comment: Its a Windows 10. I am not interested in rainmeter,and would like something cleaner like this.

Comment: You do realize that my answer contains an alternative (which is actually what's visible on your screenshot)? In addition Rainmeter would also be able to kind of get you exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tools to accomplish this. You will always need a tool to do this as it is not a Windows default. Depending on your requirements in regards to how many updates you want to see (e.g. displaying current CPU load) you might have to use one or the other.

Among other Rainmeter and BGInfo (part of the Sysinternals Suite) are tools that can be used.

As Nichlas H. pointed out the OS you're using matters as those I mentioned are Windows tools and you might have to use different tools on other operating systems.